# Phpstormツリービューの差分表示方法

Tags: phpstorm

現在githubと連携して開発しているのですが
ツリービューの表示で
差分のあるファイルは異なる色で表示されていますが
該当ファイルだけでなくファイルの親ディレクトリの色も変更させたいのですが
Phpstormでこのような設定はできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

File > Settings > Version Control　まで開いて

> Show directories with changed descendants

にチェックを入れるとできます。